# Why is smoothScrollToPosition not registering as onScrollStateChanged event

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I register a `OnScrollListener` to a `ListView`. When programmatically executing `smoothScrollToPosition` `onScrollStateChanged` method of the listener is never executed. Why? Is there a way to tell when scrolling has finished.

I initialize my list view like that:

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
initializeListeners();
....
```

And the code of `initializeListeners`:

```
private void initializeListeners() {
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Log.i(TAG, "scroll is idle");
            }
        }
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount,
                        int totalItemCount) {
             Log.i(TAG, "scrolling");
        }
    });
```

**When I call `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);` this will not trigger `onScrollStateChanged`. Why? Is there a way to tell when scrolling has finished?**

Comment: You will get an OnItemSelected callback instead.